# Can I use Bibtex to print a bibliography of a document, but not the document, to a .pdf file

Tags: bibtex

I have a large LaTeX file which has several hundred references in its `.bib` file. Can anyone tell me if it is possible to print the list of references, including all of the details each `@INPROCEEDINGS`, `@BOOK`, `@MISC` etc. `bibtex` entry, from the `.bib` file to a `.pdf` file without printing the document itself?

I am using `PDTLATEX` in `WinEdt 9` with `MikTeX 2.9` in `Windows 10`.

Comment: just copy the .bbl file generated for the big document to a new name of an otherwise empty document and don't run bibtex on the small document so it gets over-written.

Comment: or `\nocite{*}` and `\bibliography` (+ style) in an otherwise empty document.

Comment: or extract pages (print to file, or ghostscript) from the full pdf, provided that the references start on a new page.

Comment: @David Carlisle: Can you please make an answer of your suggestion and I will answer it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just copy the `.bbl` file generated for the big document to a new name of an otherwise empty document and don't run bibtex on the small document so it gets over-written. Latex the small document and it will input the bibliography as normal.